# Xampp no funciona en MacOs

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, cakephp, macos, localhost

me baje el Xampp en Mac y no me corre la forma grafica de este en la pagina web o no se si en Mac se usa de una forma diferente a como lo usaba en Windows, aquí les envio un pantallazo de mi problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como pueden ver en la imagen cuando abro localhost/xampp no me muestra la pagina Index del y cuando voy a intentar correr el phpmyadmin no lo inicia, siempre se queda intentando iniciar un rato y luego se detiene.

La version del Xampp que me baje es esta: 5.6.36 / PHP 5.6.36

debido a que CakePHP 2.x no corre sino con esa versión.

Si pongo localhost sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual esta bien, pero si le doy a phpmyadmin sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y si pones simplemente **`http://localhost`** qué pasa?

Comment: @A.Cedano ya te subo  pantallazo

Comment: @A.Cedano listo, ya subí la imagen

Comment: Eso ya parece ser una cuestión de permisos. Revisa las configuraciones de usuario / contraseña  para conectar a la base de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano donde puedo ver con que usuario se esta intentando conectar?

Comment: No sé exactamente, no uso Xampp, pero si revisas las configuraciones lo encontrarás, supongo.

Comment: @A.Cedano son estas lineas?
`# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password = your_password
port  = 3306
socket  = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket  = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M`

Comment: Revisa [estas instrucciones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42086131/5587982)  o bien [estas otras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115070/5587982).

Comment: podrías intentar con MAMP es más fácil de usar y de configurar yo deje XAMMP porque complica mucho las cosas.